# pyodbc multiple SQL queries

Tags: python, pyodbc

I am using **pyodbc** and I want to return lots of data from different tables.  What is the most efficient way to do this? Do I have to create a new connection each time or can I reuse one?

```
import pyodbc

def docLauncher(connetStr):
    conn = pyodbc.connect(connetStr)
    cursor = conn.cursor()

    cursor.execute('SELECT COLUMN1 FROM TABLE1')
    companyName = cursor.fetchone()[0]

    conn1 = pyodbc.connect(connetStr)
    cursor1 = conn1.cursor()

    cursor1.execute('SELECT COLUMN2 FROM TABLE2')
    ver = cursor1.fetchone()[0]

    print(companyName)
    print(ver)
```

Comment: You don't have to create a new connection each time unless you're accessing multiple databases. If you're just accessing different tables in one database then just creating a connection once is fine.

Answer (score 2):

You do not have to create new connections, just one is sufficient. However, if you're looking to return a lot of data, I would not use the `fetch` functions. I have found this to be very time-consuming. This is how I access pyodbc and return millions of rows to work with (you can put this inside your docLauncher() function if you want):

```
import pyodbc

conn = pyodbc.connect(connection_string)
crsr = conn.cursor()

my_data = crsr.execute(sql_string)

for row in my_data:
    # do something with your data here
    print(row)

my_data_2 = crsr.execute(sql_string_2)

for row_2 in my_data_2:
    print(row_2)
```

This can be very useful if you want to export your data (to csv, for example). Instead of this:

```
for row in my_data:
    print(row)
```

You would do this:

```
with open(file_name, 'w', newline='') as csvfile:
    writer = csv.writer(csvfile)
    writer.writerow([x[0] for x in crsr.description])  # column headers
    for row in my_data:
        writer.writerow(row)
```

Using the `for` loop reduces my processing times from over an hour to just a few minutes (~3 minutes for 5 million rows x 30 columns).